# Prisma exclude link table when fetching relation

Tags: javascript, prisma

Does anyone know if Prisma has a way to avoid unnecessary nesting levels when fetching nested objects through the link table?

Schema:

```
model User {
    id            String    @id @default(cuid())
    name          String?
    email         String?   @unique
    emailVerified DateTime?
    image         String?
    accounts      Account[]
    sessions      Session[]
    roles         UsersRoles[]
    created_at    DateTime  @default(now())
}

model Role {
    id    Int @id @default(autoincrement())
    name  AllowedRoles @default(USER)
    users UsersRoles[]
}

model UsersRoles {
    userId String
    user   User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
    roleId Int
    role   Role @relation(fields: [roleId], references: [id])

    @@id([userId, roleId])
}
```

In the screenshot you see that I must do

```
include: {
    roles: {
        include: {
            role: true
        }
    }
}
```

to get the role id and name, but I also get the unnecessary data from the link table/pivot table. Can I query the role data directly, without getting the pivot table in the result?
It works with Prisma implicit many to many relationships, but I want to do with explicit

[image]

Edit 1:
Found this https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/troubleshooting-orm/help-articles/working-with-many-to-many-relations
Prisma shows an example how to get rid of link table data:

```
const result = posts.map((post) => {
  return { ...post, tags: post.tags.map((tag) => tag.tag) }
})
```

I guess since even in Prisma docs they do it like this, there is no way to do so during fetching time with Prisma client. But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try swapping out your top-level `include` for a `select`. Prisma will return all scalar (non-relation) fields by default unless you specify a `select` object.

[relevant docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/select-fields)